# Unable to get value properly from material select

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-forms

I have the following angular material custom component:

material-select-component.html

```
<mat-select
      matNativeControl
      [(ngModel)]="_value"
      (selectionChange)="valueChanged($event)"
      [placeholder]="labelName"
      [required]="required"
    >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option[optionValue]">
        <div class="imc-mat-option">
          <p>{{ option[optionLabel] }}</p>
          <p class="option-key">{{ option[optionKey] }}</p>
        </div></mat-option
      >
    </mat-select>
```

and this is the ts code:

material-select-component.ts

```
export class MaterialSelectComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() options = [];
  @Input() labelName: String = '';
  @Input('defaultValue') _value: String = '';
  @Input() optionLabel: String = '';
  @Input('_tabindex') tabindex: number = 1;
  @Input() optionValue: String = 'id';
  @Input() required: boolean = false;
  @Output() change = new EventEmitter<string>();

  onChange: any = () => {};
  onTouched: any = () => {};

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.value = this._value;
  }

  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }

  set value(val) {
    this._value = val;
    this.onChange(val);
    this.onTouched();
  }

  constructor() {}

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  writeValue(value) {
    if (value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  valueChanged(event) {
    this.value = event.value;
    this.change.emit(event.value);
  }
}
```

and I'm using it like this:

my-component.html

```
    <form *ngIf="myForm" [formGroup]="myForm">
 <app-input
            labelName="stack"
            formControlName="stack"
            validationName="stack"
          ></app-input>
        <app-custom-select
                    id="mydata"
                    formControlName="my_attr"
                    labelName="data"
                    validationName="id"
                    optionLabel="id"
                    optionKey="description"
                    [options]="myData"
                    (change)="getValues($event)"
                  >
                  </app-custom-select>
    </form>
```

and my my-component.ts:

```
export class myComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  @Input() item = {};
  @Input() myData = [];

  @Output() remove = new EventEmitter<customType>(true);
  @Output() update = new EventEmitter<Partial<customType>>(true);

  id: string = ''; // here I cannot get data
  description: string = ''; // here I cannot get data

  constructor(private changeDetectRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm();
  }
initForm(): void {
    const {
      stack
    } = this.item;

    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      stack: new FormControl(stack, [Validators.required]),
      myattr: new FormGroup({
        id: new FormControl(this.id), // I cannot get the data here
        description: new FormControl(this.description), // I cannot get the data here
      })
    });

    this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(this.onFormChange);
  }
onFormChange = (myItem) => {
    if (!this.myForm.valid) {
      this.update.emit({
        stack: 0,
      });
      return;
    }

    myItem.myattr['id'] = parseInt(
      myItem.myattr['id'].toString()
    );
    myItem.myattr['description'] = parseInt(
      myItem.myattr['description'].toString()
    );

    this.update.emit(myItem);
  };

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.changeDetectRef.detectChanges();
  }

  getValues({ id, description }) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    console.log('VALUES', this.description, this.id); // here I can see the data!
  }
```

So the issue is that I'm successfully achieving the data but I cannot assign them into my form, so I'm trying to show the id next to the description in the select and I'm successfully showing them, and in my my-component.ts I can log them in getValues() but cannot RETRIEVE them in the form after assigning them! so any idea folks?

Comment: have you defined the myattr FormGroup in your template?

Comment: I don't need an extra control, I just need to extract the key and the value selected from my   my custom select as it is shown, but somehow it is now adding them to my inputs

Comment: Nesting a form group doesn't add a control. Can we see the rest of your template?

Comment: the rest of my template doesn't make any difference because I have only a select and an input but I have updated it, check it out

Comment: formControlName="my_attr"  - this name doesn't match any of your controls

Comment: As I can see and I did, the app-custom-select name is my_attr which is in formControlName, so what do you mean by it doesnt match with any of my controls?

Comment: In my-component.ts where you are setting this.form. The formControlName in the template needs to match what you have defined in your FormGroup

Comment: but for now it is matched, no? as I have formControlName="stack" and formControlName="my_attr" but the others I'm getting them throught the select, so isn't that possible?